# How can i split the string like shown in example below

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a string like below

```
string str = "ABE,1A2B3CD,1B2A3C,1A2BC3E";
```

How can i split this string and set it to the list like below?

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst[0] = "A";  
lst[1] = "B";  
lst[2] = "E";  
lst[3] = "1A2B3CD";  
lst[4] = "1B2A3C";  
lst[5] = "1A2BC3E";
```

Comment: You might want to explain how you arrive at that list. It's not simply a [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) on a comma. How do you arrive at A / B / E ?

Comment: What are the rules you're following here? Is it *always* a case of splitting the list by commas, but then treating each character in the first string as its own entry? A single example doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: -1 for letting us guess what you want. You should explain such things in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
string[] s = str.Split(',');
if (s.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (char c in s[0])
        lst.Add(c.ToString());
    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
        lst.Add(s[i]);
}
```

I assumed that you need to split every string delimited by a comma and, for the first only, every single char...

Comment: best effort possible pending clarification of the question :)

Comment: I did my own attempt at interpreting it now ;)

Comment: @sehe: ...and you got +1 from me for your effort. Great code!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want string that don't start with a digit split into separate characters:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var split = str.Split(',').SelectMany(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d")
          ? new [] {s} 
          : s.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()))
     .ToList();
```

split:

```
{ "A", "B", "E", "1A2B3CD", "1B2A3C", "1A2BC3E" }
```